# Qt listview - too sensitive for scroll compared to click

Tags: qt, qml

Is there a way  to make a Flickable less sensitive to flicks?

Since I use the application in a bumpy environment the clicks on the MouseArea inside the ListView are sometimes registered as flicks. 
(I hope there is a quick solution, but a more complicated, or an ugly solution might work as well)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`preventStealing`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#preventStealing-prop) from `MouseArea`. From the docs:

> This property holds whether the mouse events may be stolen from this MouseArea.
>
> **If a MouseArea is placed within** an item that filters child mouse
>   events, such as **Flickable**, **the mouse events may be stolen** from the
>   MouseArea if a gesture is recognized by the parent item, e.g. a flick
>   gesture. **If preventStealing is set to true, no item will steal the
>   mouse events**.
>
> Note that setting preventStealing to true once an item has started
>   stealing events will have no effect until the next press event.
>
> **By default this property is false**.

If this property does not suffice, you can try to work on the `Flickable` properties, e.g. [`pressDelay`](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#pressDelay-prop).

### EDIT

`setStartDragDistance(ms)` is still available in Qt5 (code linked in comment is about the Qt Window System that - `QWS`, AFAIK is not supported any more since Qt 5.0 came out). The call is exposed by `QApplication` even if you should have a `QGuiApplication`. `QApplication`/`QGuiApplication` are responsible for managing the so called main event loop and in general for setting up the environment for QML code execution. It is located in your `main.cpp` file and that's where you should place the code.

As said, such a method is exposed by `QApplication`. The latter *internally* forwards the call to `QGuiApplication`. To use `QApplication` you need to import widgets, i.e. add `QT += widgets` to your `.pro` file ([feature request link](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-43119)). Instead of that we can expose the private GUI APIs and access the corresponding method inside `QGuiApplication`. To do so just 1) add to your `.pro` file `QT += gui_private` and 2) open your `main.cpp` and edit your code so that it looks like the following:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);          // <--- app definition already present
QStyleHints * sh = app.styleHints();
sh->setStartDragDistance(/* NEW VALUE */);
// other code...
```

Run `QMake` and recompile to apply the change.

If you does not fill confortable in using private APIs, add to the `.pro` file the `QT += widgets` import and substitute the `QGuiApplication` with `QApplication`. Then your `main.cpp` should look like the following code:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);          // <--- now a QApplication
QApplication::setStartDragDistance(/* NEW VALUE */);
// other code...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Unfortunately preventStealing and pressDelay dont do the work. PreventStealing makes it almost impossible to flick the view at all, and pressDelay just makes it harder to click or gives more unintentioned clicks.

I think I am after something like this:
app->setStartDragDistance(20)
I found this code here: http://www.qtforum.org/article/38560/porting-application-from-qt4-7-3-to-qt5-0beta1.html, but I am just familiar with qml and javascript so I don't understand how I can use it. Does anyone have a clue if I am on the right path?

Comment: @Johan I've edited the answer with the required details. Private APIs used in the first approach proposed are not likely to change. Hence, I would go for that way of using `setStartDragDistance`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again! I didn't managed to do any changes to the drag sensitiveness. The first solution (to use private GUI API) gave me some error messages, and I had since before tried out the second variant (with the addition that I had to add '#include <QApplication>' in my main.cpp file). setStartDragDistance() seems for me to not affect the sensitivity in a listView. Maybe it just work for Drag&Drop, or maybe I couldn't get it to work due to my lack of skills in programming ;) .

Comment: Many thanks for trying to help me out. Since my application is just a prototype I will continue with a "dirty" solution by manually counting the distance for the drag, and trigger a click if the distance is less than my limit.

Comment: You're welcome. *Maybe it just work for Drag&Drop* NO. Just don't guess. Each time I provide an answer I test the code before (at least when necessary). I've tested the code myself on a `ListView` and it happens to work perfectly (the flicking starts as soon as the set threshold is reached, not before).  Did you try to set a bigger value? As for the private APIs, did you run `QMake` and then did a full rebuild (`clean All`)? If that doesn't work, it could be worth have a check for the errors you got. Anyhow, if you are really, really, really happy with your current solution...that's it, ok. :)

Comment: You motivate me to try it out once again :) But I don't have more time right now, so maybe in the future.

Comment: I was just pointing out that I'm not used to provide half-working answers. At least I try my best to not do so! :)